# Command to Get Calling Server's Name

Tags: shell-script, ssh, who

A shell script running on a batch server will `ssh` (`ssh -n root@prodfs1`) to the file server to run another shell script, but we'd like to run subsequent shell scripts back on the original batch server. The `who` command does not return the name of the server that initiated the process. Is there a command that will provide the server name of the parent process? Thanks.

Comment: Are the "subsequent shell scripts" kicked off from the shell script started on the batch server? If so look at the SSH_CONNECTION and SSH_CLIENT environment variable set up by openssh.

Comment: The subsequent shell scripts are not kicked off from the initial shell script.

Comment: Can you explain the requirements a little more. You have 2 machines "batch server" and "file server". You start a program on the "batch server". One action it does is use ssh to run a second program on the "file server".  You now want to run "subsequent shell scripts" (programs 3, 4 and 5 for example) on the "batch server". What is the parent of 3,4 and 5, is it program 1 (which is already running on "batch server") or program 2 (which is running on "file server")? If it is program 2, are you going to use ssh from "file" to "batch" to start programs 3,4,5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to achieve desired results using the following:

```
SSHSERVER=$(echo $SSH_CLIENT | cut -d " " -f1)
SSHSERVERNAME=$(host $SSHSERVER | cut -d " " -f5 | sed "s/.$//")
```

Thanks to icarus for pointing us in the right direction.

Comment: If you have a POSIX shell `SSHSERVER=${SSH_CLIENT%% *}` is more efficient. Most things that accept hostnames will also accept ip addresses. The `host` command may or may not get you a usable hostname, depending on if the reverse address lookup has been populated.